# interface angular usage in for loop

Tags: angular, typescript, oop, interface

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
export interface User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-typeof-otcsection',
  templateUrl: './typeof-otcsection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./typeof-otcsection.component.css']
})
export class TypeofOTCSectionComponent implements OnInit {
user!: User[];
userList=any;
constructor() {}
ngOnInit(): void {
this.user={"id":0,"name":""}
}

let z=1
for (let k = 0; k < ((userarrayfromDB).length); k++) {
let user =this.user 
user.id=z
user.name=userarrayfromDB[k].name
userList.push(user)
z++
}
}
```

So I am working on an angular project, I have made an interface called user, and using the interface I have made the object ie **this.user** . So suppose the **userarrayfromDB** length is 3 and when I am pushing the user object in userlist array , it is pushing the last array 3 times

for Example

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "nishit"
        
    }
],
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "nishit"
    }
],
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "nishit"
    }
]
```

I want the user list array like the below example

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "test"
            
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "test2"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "nishit"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Ok, I will try that and will let you know. Thanks

Comment: But can you explain to me why my last array only inserted 3 times

Comment: Correction for previous comment: Expect that the push user into array logic should be in a method. From your code, the logic was in the global which is incorrect. While you don't need to declare `z` variable for the index. Instead, `user.id = k + 1` does the same job.

Comment: @Nishitbhardwaj when you do `let user = this.user` and then push the `user` variable in the array, it's always the same object reference that you are pushing, 3 times. Whenever you modify that instance once, all its references will be updated. Try `let user = {...this.user};` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular scenario, you don't necessarily need a for loop to move some data from one array to another. You could do it all in one line like this:

```
this.userList = [...userarrayfromDB];
```

In case your `userarrayfromDB` contains objects of a different shape (for example, they have more properties than you need), then you can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to project the data in the desired form:

```
this.userList = userarrayfromDB.map(user => {
  const result = { id: user.id, name: user.name };
  
  // conditionally assign more properties here.

  return result;
});
```

Comment: how can I add an if and else condition ??

Comment: What do you need to check exactly? The `map` handler can be expanded with curly braces and you can do whatever you need there.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let users = [[{"id":3,"name":"nishit"}],[{"id":3,"name":"nishit"}],[{"id":3,"name":"nishit"}]];
var  index=1;
var usersList = users.map(record =>{
  let user = record[0];
  user.id=index;
  user.name="test"+index;
  index++;
  return user;
  });
console.log(usersList)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).